# Method to Update Category Attribute Without Loading the Category Model

Tags: category, attributes, model, category-attribute

When updating product attributes, this method would suffice so that it would prevent loading the whole product model:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array(1,2,3),
    array('some_attribute'=>'some value',
          'some_attribute_2'=>'some value',
         ),
    0
);
```

Is there a function related to this to update the category attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no function is existing,which will do    like `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()`

So,***let create a module*** which will do same like `catalog/product_action`.

### In this case need to  create a new resource model & resource class.

On the ***resource class*** , i have define a function which update `category attribute quickly like product`.

**So config.xml like:**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <[modelindefier]> <!-- this also call module model group class prefix -->
            <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>[modelindefier]_resource</resourceModel>
        </custommodule>
        <[modelindefier]_resource>
            <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Resource</class>
        </[modelindefier]_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

**The resource class which do like this.**

***class :***  `[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Resource_Category_Action`

***function :***  `updateAttributes(params)`

> ```
> <?php
>
> /**
>  * Catalog category attribute quick update
>  *
>  * @author      Amit Bera<dev.amitbera@gmail.com>
>  */
> class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Resource_Category_Action extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract
> {
>     /**
>      * Intialize connection
>      *
>      */
>     protected function _construct()
>     {
>         $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
>         $this->setType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY)
>             ->setConnection(
>                 $resource->getConnection('catalog_read'),
>                 $resource->getConnection('catalog_write')
>             );
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Update attribute values for entity list per store
>      *
>      * @param array $entityIds
>      * @param array $attrData
>      * @param int $storeId
>      * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Action
>      */
>     public function updateAttributes($entityIds, $attrData, $storeId)
>     {
>         $this->_attributeValuesToSave   = array();
>         $this->_attributeValuesToDelete = array();
>
>         $object = new Varien_Object();
>         $object->setIdFieldName('entity_id')
>             ->setStoreId($storeId);
>
>         $this->_getWriteAdapter()->beginTransaction();
>         try {
>             foreach ($attrData as $attrCode => $value) {
>                 $attribute = $this->getAttribute($attrCode);
>                 if (!$attribute->getAttributeId()) {
>                     continue;
>                 }
>
>                 $i = 0;
>                 foreach ($entityIds as $entityId) {
>                     $i++;
>                     $object->setId($entityId);
>                     // collect data for save
>                     $this->_saveAttributeValue($object, $attribute, $value);
>                     // save collected data every 1000 rows
>                     if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
>                         $this->_processAttributeValues();
>                     }
>                 }
>                 $this->_processAttributeValues();
>             }
>             $this->_getWriteAdapter()->commit();
>         } catch (Exception $e) {
>             $this->_getWriteAdapter()->rollBack();
>             throw $e;
>         }
>
>         return $this;
>     }
> }
> ```

Now you have call class function by using below code:

```
 Mage::getResourceModel('modelindefier/category_action')->updateAttributes(
    array(5,10,11),
    array('some_attribute'=>'some value',
          'some_attribute'=>'some value2',
         ),
    0
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> No any function is available to update category attribute without
>   loading category model